# Expo build failed

Tags: javascript, java, apk, expo

Currently failed to build my expo apk, not sure why.

I just pulled the latest version from my desktop but it works fine when I previously built on my laptop.

Anyways, the app runs fine when I test it & I can confirm I pulled the latest version of my app.

Building for iPhone works fine, but fails for Android.
Here is the error log:

```
:app:transformClassesWithDexForProdRelease
[stderr] Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
[stderr] Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
[stderr] This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
[stderr] If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
[stderr] targetCompatibility = '1.7'
[stderr] sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
[stderr] to that submodule's build.gradle file.
[stderr]     UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[stderr]     java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:781)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:747)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:88)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1689)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:695)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:560)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:376)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:290)
[stderr]        at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:54)
[stderr]        at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.lambda$dexInProcess$0(DexByteCodeConverter.java:174)
[stderr]        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[stderr]        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[stderr]        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[stderr]        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[stderr]     Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:476)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:793)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1600(Main.java:88)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1728)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:779)
[stderr]        ... 16 more
[stderr]     
[stderr] Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
[stderr] Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
[stderr] This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
[stderr] If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
[stderr] targetCompatibility = '1.7'
[stderr] sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
[stderr] to that submodule's build.gradle file.
[stderr]     UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[stderr]     java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:781)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:747)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:88)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1689)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:695)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:587)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:376)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:290)
[stderr]        at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:54)
[stderr]        at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.lambda$dexInProcess$0(DexByteCodeConverter.java:174)
[stderr]        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[stderr]        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[stderr]        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[stderr]        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[stderr]     Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:476)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:793)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1600(Main.java:88)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1728)
[stderr]        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:779)
[stderr]        ... 16 more
[stderr]     
[stderr] 2 errors; aborting
 FAILED
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForProdRelease'.
[stderr] > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 9 mins 20.306 secs
```

I'm not familiar with java, so I can't trace where it went wrong.
My `app.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "myApp",
    "icon": "./src/images/myApp.png",
    "version": "1.1.1",
    "description": "myApp description",
    "sdkVersion": "25.0.0",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.myApp.myApp",
      "infoPlist": {
        "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes": ["whatsapp"],
        "NSCameraUsageDescription":
          "This app uses the camera"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.myApp.myApp",
      "versionCode": 4
    },
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/spashpage.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover"
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone know the reason?

Comment: I'm facing to the same sitituation, and don't know why? I can do the build normally in the morning, then update some business logic in code, and build failed in the evening :| Maybe there is something wrong on Expo server last 12 hours

Comment: connected to this issue: https://forums.expo.io/t/android-standalone-build-failed/11065
Should be solved by now

Comment: @doannx okay, thanks for your reply. I thought I had some err in my code. So I guess this could be a problem on their side.

Comment: @DrorAharon thanks